# problemas cargando vistas parciales fuertemente tipadas con ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

tengo el siguiente código que a treves de jquery, intenta traer los datos de una vista parcial y mostrarlos en la vista principal. el tema es que al iniciar el proceso, y hacer click en el botón correspondiente, el evento load, no carga nada, por ende los datos no se insertan en la vista.

este es el el actiontresult en el controller que me trae los datos (lo simplifique para efectos de mostrarlo aca)

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ObtenerCliente()
    {
        Cliente cliente;
        cliente = new Cliente();
        cliente.Nombre = "raul";
        cliente.Apellido = "perez";
        cliente.edad = 23;
        objCliente.Add(cliente);

        cliente = new Cliente();
        cliente.Nombre = "Juan";
        cliente.Apellido = "torres";
        cliente.edad = 22;
        objCliente.Add(cliente);
        return PartialView("DetalleCliente", objCliente);
    }
```

aca esta la vista principal y el script donde hago la llamada

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn1').click(function () {
            $('#dvDetalleCliente').load('/home/ObtenerCliente');
        });
    });
</script>
```

cuando depuro la ejecución, en chrome, puedo ver claramente que se ejecuta el evento click, pero al parecer el load, no esta cargando los datos.. jamas llega el control al actionresult en el controller.

Alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal?

Saludos

Comment: Luis, además de la depuración en Chrome ubica dentro de esa misma consola la pestaña `Network` y busca el momento donde se llama a `/home/ObtenerCliente`, para visualizar que error está ocurriendo justo en ese instante.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu ayuda, aparentemente tenia un problema en el div que contenia los datos (tenia un display:none, que vebnia con el ejemplo que estoy siguiendo. muchas gracias